# Devise and user registration requiring admin approval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I would like to implement the following registration system :

1. User signs up and is redirected
   to a thank you for signing up page
   (is NOT sent an email and cannot yet log in)
2. Admin logs in and sees list of newly registered (but as yet unapproved) users
3. Admin edits user details and clicks 'Approved' which then sends email with password to new user

How can I do this with Devise?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is answered in a page on the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in).